# Sencha - Add new form field Sencha form using button - user activates

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

Ok, I'm probably missing something basic here but I wanted to see if someone can catch what is going wrong here.  My goal is to have the user be able to add a new ingredient (via new textfield in my recipe form) by clicking a button in the Sencha-based form.

Also the textfield name (to be submitted) needs to be incremented by 1 so the submission to the MySQL database works properly, i.e. ingredients2, ingredients3 ...here is what I have so far (without the model), Also notice I have hardcoded the fields bu have hidden them for testing purposes:

```
        var formBase = {
        scroll: 'vertical',
        url   : 'server.php',
        standardSubmit : false,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Add Recipe',
                ref: 'fs',
                //instructions: 'Please enter the information above.',
                defaults: {
                    required: true,
                    labelAlign: 'left',
                    labelWidth: '40%',
                },

                items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'name',
                    label: 'Recipe Name',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients',
                    label: 'Ingredients',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients2',
                    label: 'Ingredients 2',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients3',
                    label: 'Ingredients 3',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients4',
                    label: 'Ingredients 4',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients5',
                    label: 'Ingredients 5',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients6',
                    label: 'Ingredients 6',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients7',
                    label: 'Ingredients 7',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients8',
                    label: 'Ingredients 8',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'ingredients9',
                    label: 'Ingredients 9',
                    useClearIcon: true,
                    autoCapitalize : false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    name : 'comments',
                    label: 'Comments',
                    maxLength: 50,
                    maxRows: 5,
                    height: 120
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    name : 'email',
                    label: 'Email',
                    placeHolder: 'user@foo.com',
                    useClearIcon: true
                },
                {
                                xtype:'button',
                                text: 'Add Ingredient',
                                handler: function() {

                                 var p = formBase.fs.items.items + 1;
                                   formBase.fs.insert(p, {  
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        name : 'ingredients',
                                        label: 'Added field'
                                   });
                                   formBase.fs.doLayout();
                                }},

                ]

            }
        ],
```

The error I am receiving is:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Thanks for any and all help! - BRR

Answer (score 1):

```
    defaults: {
                required: true,
                labelAlign: 'left',
                labelWidth: '40%',
            },
```

That comma after labelWidth would break it wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it does not affect it but thanks for the catch.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Any chance you have a more complete example? Some random object ( and not all of it ) makes it a bit hard. Which line does the Exception happen on ( I am guessing it is at the var p bit, as that feels a tad strange, but this is guess work ) ? I am not sure if you can just var p = formBase.fs.items.items + 1; inside an objectlike that, maybe you are looking for... var p=count(formbase....);

Comment: Actually that is a pretty complete example - the rest just builds out other panels on the page.  The exception occurs at the line you mentioned (var p...) and I believe you are correct I need some sort of count function.  I ended up rolling my own function which fires off a different docked button; it's not pretty but got the job done.  If you want to see I can post it - too long for this comment.

Answer (score 0):

On the line p= formBase.fs.items.items + 1; 
The field fs is not defined as a property on the formBase variable, so it is not being resolved (thus it is undefined).  Therefore when attempting to reference 'items' within 'fs' you are getting an error.  (you are attempting to reference items within fs, and fs is undefined).